# How to prevent user interaction before opening complex Qt dialogs

Tags: lazy-initialization, qdialog

I have complex dialog (it has a lot of widgets that take some time to be created) which at the end of its constructor calls `QDialog::exec()`. And I want to disallow the user to open it several times by double-clicking on some action a few times.

E.g. When a user trigger some action to open the dialog, he has some time to click it again before `QDialog::exec()` be called and block user interaction, which will lead to creating some "dialog opening events" that will be triggered after the `first opened` dialog will be closed.

I am sure that there is some proper solution for that kind of problem. Something like block user interaction immediately and lazy dialog widgets loading.